# uncaught target signal 11 в qemu для arm при сборке с помощью arm-none-eabi-g++

Tags: c++, arm, qemu

Мне необходимо скомпилировать и запустить простейший код на *C++* под *ARM*.
Пытаюсь сделать:

```
$arm-none-eabi-g++ -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m3 -static --specs=nosys.specs test.cpp
```

На выходе получаю файл:

```
$file a.out

a.out: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, not stripped
```

При запуске:

```
$qemu-arm -cpu cortex-m3 a.out

qemu: uncaught target signal 11 (Segmentation fault) - core dumped
Ошибка сегментирования (core dumped)
```

В чем моя ошибка? Запуск производится на `Fedora`.
Код:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Решение:

```
 $ arm-none-eabi-g++ -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m3 --specs=rdimon.specs -Wl,--start-group -lgcc -lc -lm -lrdimon -Wl,--end-group -o test test.cpp
```

Запуск:

```
 $ qemu-arm -cpu cortex-m3 ./test
```

Вывод:

```
Hello World!
```